# PHP shell_exec command only works from command line

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am trying to create a Youtube Downloader inspired by Nimesh Neema answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/downloading-youtube-music-videos/321668?noredirect=1#comment409948_321668.  It uses the `youtube-dl` command.

**youtube.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$command = '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU --no-check-certificate -f mp4 -o     /Library/WebServer/Documents/files/test.mp4';
$command1 = 'sleep 2; echo "hi"';
shell_exec($command);
echo '<pre>';
passthru($command);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

When accused through a web browser nothing happens.  But if I run `php ./youtube.php` in Terminal I get the following and the video is created:

```
<pre>[youtube] b91ovTKCZGU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] b91ovTKCZGU: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] b91ovTKCZGU: Extracting video information
[download] /Library/WebServer/Documents/files/test.mp4 has already been    downloaded
[download] 100% of 10.09MiB
```

If that isn't odd enough.  If I change the command to be executed to `/usr/bin/touch /Library/WebServer/Documents/files/test.mp4` it creates the file even when accessed through a web browser.

**My Question**: How can I get the PHP script to execute the command when accessed through a browser and successfully create the video?

**If you are going to downvote please explain the reason why in the comments so I can edit and adjust the question as needed**

**Update**: I transferred the script to my server.  It ran perfectly.  It seems to be an issue with my configuration.

Comment: @JaredFarrish How come `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in.......`

Comment: Cool, go for it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please remove downvote. Or at least explain why you down voted.

Comment: Then remove this line `$url = escapeshellarg($_GET["url"]);`, apparently unnecessary line and you will get rid of the apparently irrelevant error

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the question as requested.

Comment: Might be worth running it again and checking that the  `Undefined index` error has also gone away, so others dont get confused

Comment: Have you checked that the `shell_exec()` functions has not been disabled by your hosting company?

Comment: Please check your server logs for errors, you might not have access to shell functions based on your web-related php configuration. This is pretty common in shared environments.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have reran and edited as needed.  I was hosting the website on my localhost and then am going to move it to a server I own and run. I don't think that, that is the issue as I was able to run the `touch` command.

Comment: It would still be useful to check that it will still run on your hosting package before bothering to fix it on your local system

Comment: @RiggsFolly As I said before, I run the server. I have full access to the configuration files.  I don't have a hosting package because I do not pay to host my website, because I host it myself on my server, that I run, configure, and use.

Comment: What does your apache log say when you run the script from the web url?

Comment: It does not appear to say anything. The access log and the error log do not have anything that appears to be a sign of execution of a command or and error with that command.

Comment: Debug it like the page isn't being run then. Start at that and work your way into it once you confirm the proper execution sequence (scrip runs, then output the command, then the next part, etc). Once you know for a fact it's being run and the command appears correct, then debug what it's actually doing with the command.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean.  I attempted to change the command to the `touch` command and it worked. I also tried the `sleep` command to see if the execution time was too short but that worked too.

Comment: @JBis I have the same problem right now. Did you get a solution?